# How can i let the user enter the price and choose the currency type from the select list?

Tags: angular

How can I populate the select box with the currency types available in the world?  Is the data already available in angular?  Or should that be a hard coded? 
I need to have a text box where user can enter the price and select box next to it to choose the currency type.

Comment: Can you tell me why did you down vote my question?

Comment: It's probably you haven't included any code and showed what have you tried. Have you checked: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ?

Comment: I don't have any programming error.  I'am about try that  feature based on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't have all currencies built-in.

If you want to do that, you will have to do it on your own.

You can see https://gist.github.com/Fluidbyte/2973986 for instance.